# Serialization "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

Tags: c#, serialization

Few days ago I've asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45455188/serialize-object-to-string) about object serialization and the answer was working well, actually it still works. But somehow I've copied the serialize function to an another class but didn't fit here and I have no idea why.

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> Inner Exception: An invalid argument was supplied.

Client.cs

```
public class Client
{
    private string username;
    public string Username
    {
        get { return username; }
        set { username = value; }
    }
    private TcpClient tclient;
    public TcpClient tClient
    {
        get { return tclient; }
        set { tclient = value; }
    }
    public Client()
    {}

    public string Serialize(object obj)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Serialize(obj);
    }
    public object Deserialize(string json)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Deserialize<object>(json);
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd be pretty sure you'll not be able to serialise a `TcpClient`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the TcpClient class is not a serializable class you can't simply serialize it. But as you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) it has a constructor with (string: server, int: port) so you can add these fields to your class then after deserialization you can create it again.

Ps: It's funny that I was the one answered your previous question, here we are again.